# Terraform: get account id for provider + for_each + account module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to create multiple AWS Accounts in an Organization containing ressources.
The resources should owned by the created accounts.

for that I created a module for the accounts:

```
resource "aws_organizations_account" "this" {
  name      = var.customer
  email     = var.email
  parent_id = var.parent_id
  role_name = "OrganizationAccountAccessRole"
  provider = aws.src
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
  bucket  = "exconcept-terraform-state-${var.customer}"
  provider = aws.dst
  depends_on  = [
    aws_organizations_account.this
  ]
}
output "account_id" {
  value = aws_organizations_account.this.id
}
output "account_arn" {
  value = aws_organizations_account.this.arn
}
```

my provider file for the module:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
      configuration_aliases = [ aws.src, aws.dst ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the root module I'm calling the module like this:

```
module "account" {
  source   = "./modules/account"
  for_each = var.accounts
  customer = each.value["customer"]
  email    = each.value["email"]
  #  close_on_deletion = true
  parent_id = aws_organizations_organizational_unit.testing.id
  providers = {
    aws.src = aws.default
    aws.dst = aws.customer
  }
}
```

Since the provider information comes from the root module, and the accounts are created with a for_each map, how can I use the current aws.dst provider?

Here is my root provider file:

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-central-1"
  profile = "default"
  alias   = "default"
}

provider "aws" {
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${module.account[each.key].account_id}:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole"
  }

  alias  = "customer"
  region = "eu-central-1"
}
```

With Terraform init I got this error:

```
Error: Cycle: module.account.aws_s3_bucket_versioning.this, module.account.aws_s3_bucket.this, provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].customer, module.account.aws_s3_bucket_acl.this, module.account (close)
```

Comment: Split it into two modules: one module to create the account, one module to create the bucket and versioning and whatever in that account. I have to warn you against complex provider setups though, they will eventually bite you if you move providers around or remove an account at which point a provider would be removed which causes terraform to be very confused because it cannot deprovision resources from that provider because it no longer knows the provider, just knows that the resources were created using that provider.

Comment: @luk2302 yes, i had the same thought, I will try. Thx